# how can i filter comments in 'edit-comments.php' by special categories in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, filter

how can i filter comments in 'edit-comments.php' by special post categories in Wordpress.

```
add_action('pre_get_comments', 'filt_comm');

function filt_comm($query) {
 $query->query_vars['??'] = ??;
}
```

Comment: Check this [search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pre_get_comments+is%3Aanswer)..........

Answer (score 0):

If want to do something with edit-comments.php only in on certain category, you can try this

```
<?php
   $category = get_the_category(); 
   if($category[0]->cat_name == 'category name') {
       //Do something here;
   }
?>
```

Comment: thanks ,but i want to filter current query of edit comments page.